# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter Live icon

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I am making a radio app and noticed in the iHeartRadio app, along with the Apple Music app (Beats 1) there seems to be a Live icon for live media. I wanted to implement this into my app but have no idea on how to do it. I am using Swift 3 and MPNowPlayingInfoCenter. Any answers would help. (Icon is in the photos below called iHeart Radio LIVE icon.) Thanks!

[iHeart Radio LIVE Icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpWUe.png)

[iHeart Radio LIVE Icon 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHMeM.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift 3... the properties are in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.h

`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo =
 [MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true]`