# how to display "live" in the control center (swift iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, control-center, mpremotecommandcenter

Apple Music displays "live" inside the control center, if you hear Beats 1. Is there any way to display this "live" label and hide the normal audio progress slider?

[image]

Comment: I would assume it displays _Live_ when it actually plays a live stream

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203482/mpnowplayinginfocenter-live-icon?rq=1

Comment: I use a live stream, the controlCenter does not display "LIVE"

Comment: @PeterPajchl : this solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update this string key `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream` when update `nowPlayingInfo` dictionnary from `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`.

Here's an example:
https://github.com/noreasonprojects/ModernAVPlayer/blob/develop/Sources/Core/Services/NowPlayingService.swift